# rgdal ignoring some data

Tags: r, mapping, rgdal

I'd created a .dbf file to be read with all associated files (.shp,.shx,.prj.,.cpg), using the R package 'rgdal'. But, after reading I've noted that some data was ignored. 
When I call the input variable (which I called 'brs'), the values showed for max and min values of column 'med' is completely wrong.

```
> brs<-readOGR(dsn='/home/luis/Downloads/br_municipios',layer='BRMUE250GC_SIR')

> brs
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 5152 
extent      : -73.99045, -28.83591, -33.75118, 5.271841  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
variables   : 3
names       :      NM_MUNICIP, CD_GEOCMU,        med 
min values  : ABADIA DE GOIÁS,   1200013,       0.00 
max values  :          ZORTÉA,   5300108,     999.85
```

If I try to get those values by hand, I get:

```html
> min(brs@data$med)
[1] 0
> max(brs@data$med)
[1] 1128036
```

Performing some tests,adding new and different columns to my .dbf file, I realize that the max value accepted is around 999. Is this correct?

I need that the input variable show the correct values, because I'm trying to generate some maps using 'tmap', or 'ggmap' packages.

If someone could help, I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example

Comment: Don't trust the values showed form `print(brs)`. They are not all the time updated and are sometime part of a subsample of your data.  If the calls `min(brs@data$med)`  and `max(brs@data$med)` gives you what you are expecting, you can thrust those and your calls to `tmap` and `ggmap` should work.